# What makes UITableView behave like this

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios-autolayout

Making UI component, (let's call it SearchView) with usual UITableView inside, which contains results of search, so I have to show that results when SearchView is active and hide when not.
So I change height constraint of table view depends of that. But I meet strange behaviour of UITableView, it's not scroll content, but just moving up and down, and content is not showing. Any help will be more than appreciated. 
[View buggy UITableView](https://vimeo.com/user70241757/review/367701035/21116e6f90)

P.S. Related code is at GitHub.com/zzheads/BuggyTableView.

Comment: Add the code and the constraints that you added to the tableView.

Comment: Its too big and complexing, I don't know what makes it behave like this, I did same UI component in test project - it works fine as expected..

Comment: Without the code we won't be able to debug the issue.

Comment: Well, pushed related modules in repo: GitHub.com/zzheads/BuggyTableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I believe I found the answer after couple days struggle with that "bug".
Trying to round corners of tableView is the cause of such behaviour of tableView.
So removing 
`self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 8` 
solved the problem.